# How i display image from drive d or system drive in <img>?

Tags: html, asp.net

How i display image from drive d or system drive.

This below code not display it please help.

```
<img src="file:///D:/User/tw.png" />
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve], and how the html page is served.

Answer (score -1):

```
<img src="../../../D:/User/tw.png">
```

The code above will work if your current folder are like

```
=> C:
  => myStuff
    => projectName
      => yourCodeBelongHere
=> D:
  => User
    => tw.png
```